# How do I give HOSTNAME\Administrator access to MSSQL01 MySQL service?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, sql-server-2008

[image: test]

I got this far... but there are no Computers listed... while there are 3 other domain members: DC (Domain Controller), VCENTER and BACKUP.

I wish to give both VCENTER\Administrator and BACKUP\Administrator full administration rights to the MSSQL server.

Comment: So Vcenter and Backup are all computers on the same domain that MSSQL01 is? Are they all added to the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no built-in method for the SQL Server to authenticate the local users of another host.

You may try setting the same password for the administrator accounts on MSSQL01, VCENTER, and BACKUP. This has worked in the past for me when authenticating local accounts across separate systems, but I have not tried to do this specifically with SQL.

The general recommendation is to work around whatever issue that's preventing you from using domain accounts for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am with Hyppy. You are probably going to have to do is using sql permissions unless you either add them to your domain, or they are in another domain with a trust relationship. Another, but poor way, would be to make sure that the administrators both have the same password, and then add a local administrator with the same password: Pass-through authentication may work there.

I would add a SQL user, give it the appropriate permissions, and use that to connect from the foreign computers.

P.S. Your 0% accept rate is very conspicuous. You should go back and accept any answers that have helped you.